# How is 'you'll never miss something' said in french?

Tags: traduction, anglais

- Oh by the way, I'll bet you know that there exist paths around here that can only be trekked on foot. They can easily be recognized from the traces in the vicinity that were left by animals.
- You'll never miss them as an indicator.

This is in the context of forest-trekking and I'm trying to translate 'you'll never miss something' when something is so obviously visible that you can't reasonably pass by without noticing it. Is 'rater' a right verb to be used? I can't be certain because 'rater' seems like a verb to use when you miss a public transport like a train? Anyway, how is this usually said in French? Sorry if this is a beginner's question but I want to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

*Rater* in this case is perfectly appropriated. To translate your idea, I'd say :

> Tu ne les rateras jamais / pas

We could also say

> Tu ne peux pas les rater

(You can not miss them).

Instead of *rater*, you can also use *louper* or *manquer*, two synonyms that recall the same meaning (*louper* would be more colloquial however).